# Angular, TypeScript, шаблоны и значения по умолчанию для необязательных параметров

Tags: typescript, angular4, angular

Есть класс с полями, некоторые из которых необязательны:

```
 export class MyObjectType{
        field1?: number;
        field2?: string;
    ...
    }
```

Необходимо организовать вывод в форму шаблона значений полей объекта класса и изменение соответствующего поля класса при изменении значения в форме.
В шаблоне пока использую `[(ngModel)]`.

Проблема: в данном случае поля могут быть не определены, т.е. быть `undefined`, в связи с чем вылезает ошибка при попытке получить начальное значение для формы. Если же указать явно

```
field1: number = null;
```

тогда поля класса становятся заполненными по умолчанию `null`, и исчезает возможность отсутствия какого-либо поля.

Я пока вижу два направления - либо решить проблему средствами `TypeScript` (задать значение по умолчанию для необязательных полей класса?), либо непосредственно в шаблоне (задать значение по умолчанию для полей формы?)

Comment: А почему они у вас undefined, а не null?

Comment: @Василиса потому что значения не пустые, а не определены в принципе. Сейчас добавлю пример в вопрос.

Comment: потому `undefined` потому что нету значения у свойств, логично как бы

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @AlexPo на undefined вылезает ошибка

Comment: @Emm, вы не могли бы сделать пример на стэкблитзе? Я набросал такой пример https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ennzfe и у меня все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш класс

```
export class MyObjectType{
...
    constructor(public field1: number = null,
                public field2: string = null) {}
}
```

Ваш компонент

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: `my-component`
  template: `<h1>{{ data.field1 }} - {{ data.field2 }}</h1>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  public data: MyObjectType = new MyObjectType();
}
```

и да, `Angular` тут не причем, проблема кроется в не знании языка программирования

Comment: Собственно, в этом и вопрос заключался - неужели никак без явного указания значения null по умолчанию не обойтись? P.S. "незнании"

Comment: и да, в Вашем примере будут заполнены все поля объекта null, но тогда убирается необязательность наличия ("?") поля.

Comment: @Emm у вас другого выхода нету, это элементарный JS, я так понимаю вы пришли с другого языка. Поле все равно в рантайме будет, просто не будет инициализировано

Answer (score 1):

А в чем так сказать проблема? 
используем в шаблоне оператор `?`

```
template: `<h1>{{ data?.field1 }} - {{ data?.field2 }}</h1>`
```